# Add external Javascript to Gatsby page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I create a simple doodle jump clone after watching some tutorial. The files works fine standalone but I'm trying to import it into my gatsby site but can't seem to get it working. The game contains an `app.js` and some other resources under `src/doodle` folder. Any help on this would be appreciated as my understanding of web dev ain't the best.

`src/pages/doodle.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { withPrefix, useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

const Doodle = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query{
        site{
            siteMetadata{
                title
            }
        }
    }
    `);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Helmet>
                <title>{`${data.site.siteMetadata.title} | Doodle`}</title>
                <script src="../doodle/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            </Helmet>

            <div className="grid" ></div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Doodle;
```

`src/doodle/app.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
    const doodler = document.createElement('div');

    let doodlerLeftSpace = 50;
    let startPoint = 150;
    let doodlerBottomSpace = startPoint;
    let isGameOver = false;
    let platformCount = 5;
    let platforms = [];
    let upTimerId;
    let downTimerId;
    let leftTimerId;
    let rightTimerId;
    let isJumping = true;
    let isGoingLeft = false;
    let isGoingRight = false;
    let score = 0;
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a [`/static` folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-folder/)
- Place your `app.js` there
- Include your script in your  component

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { withPrefix, useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

const Doodle = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query{
        site{
            siteMetadata{
                title
            }
        }
    }
    `);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Helmet>
                <title>{`${data.site.siteMetadata.title} | Doodle`}</title>
                <script src={withPrefix('app.js')} type="text/javascript" />
            </Helmet>

            <div className="grid" ></div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Doodle;
  
      <Helmet>
    </Helmet>
```